# Let $V$ be a vector space, $W$ a supspace. Can we conclude that $W\oplus (V/W)$ and $V$ are isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space and $W$ is a linear subspace of $V$,can we conclude that

$$W\oplus (V/W)\cong V$$

It looks simple but I can't  see any formal proof...

Any hints or book recommendation will be welcome!

Comment: In the finite dimensional case, you can argue via dimension formula. Is this what you need? Alternatively write an element in the first space as $(v,v+[w])$, where $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. Can you check that $(v,v+[w])\mapsto v$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: @frog I know this.I was just considering the general case.It seems right,but I didn't find any clue in linear algebra book at hand...Let me have a try,hope it will work..

Comment: You can try and prove that $W$ has a complement in $V$, that is, there exists a subspace, say $W'$, of $V$ such that $V = W \oplus W'$. Then $W' \cong V/W$ and you are done.

Comment: An abstract argument (hiding details of Zorn's Lemma under the rug): every short exact sequence $0 \to W \to V \to V/W \to 0$ of modules over a field is split exact (since $V/W$ is free)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
Consider the set $\mathcal U$ all subspace $U\subseteq V$ such that the restriction $\pi|_U$ of the projection $\pi\colon V\to V/W$ is injective.
By Zorn's lemma, $\mathcal U$ has a maximal element $W'$. One verifies that $\pi|_{W'}$ is an isomorphism and then that for all spaces $X$, the map $\operatorname{Hom}(V,X)\to \operatorname{Hom}(U,X)\times \operatorname{Hom}(W,X)$, $f\mapsto (f|_U,f|_{W'}\circ(\pi|{W'})^{-1})$ is a bijection, thus showing that $V$ (together with the found inclusions) hast the universal property of direct sum.

For a less abstract approach: Pick a basis in $W$ and a basis in $V/W$ and pick a "matching" basis in $V$.